# Inverse function after sqare and multiplication

Tags: function, inverse

I'm trying to write two inverse functions.
If we pass to function A value 10 it returns for example 4,86 and if we pass that number to function B it should give us back original 10.

I'm using something like this in function A:

**output = sqrt(inputForA / range) * inputForA;**

So is it possible to reverse it in function B and calculate inputForA only knowing output and range.

Comment: Should probably be moved to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to factor that equation to single out inputForA.  Here are the algebraic steps:

output = sqrt(inputForA / range) * inputForA

output / inputForA = sqrt(inputForA / range)

sq(output) / sq(inputForA) = inputForA / range

range * sq(output) / sq(inputForA) = inputForA

range * sq(output) = cube(inputForA)

So the cube root of range times the output squared should give you your original input.  I don't have a good way of showing that in here though...

Comment: I ran through this with a simple example of input of 10 and range of 5 - it works great.

Comment: Thank you Stefan H and Sylvain Defresne. Both your methods work like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use basic math. `output = pow(inputForA, 3. / 2.) * pow(range, 1. / 2.)` so `inputForA = pow(output * pow(range, 1. / 2.), 2. / 3.)`. This only works if `inputForA` and `scale` have the same sign, but the first function is only defined on that interval, so this is okay (since `sqrt` is only defined for positive values).

In Python:

```
scale = 7.

def f(x):
    return math.sqrt(x / scale) * x

def g(y):
    return math.pow(y * math.pow(scale, 1. / 2), 2. / 3)

print g(f(10))
10.0

print f(g(10))
10.0
```

You could also have used [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inv%28sqrt%28x%20/%20theta%29%20*%20x%29) to get the answer: [image]